# Firefox Extension: File Read/Write using OS.File.jsm

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

From the [File I/O snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O)

> Use of [OS.File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File)
>   is preferred over following the examples in this article. Only use
>   these legacy interfaces if OS.File is not available to you.

Now I've got a few questions...

From [OS.File for the main thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread)

> Example: **Read the contents of a file as text**
>
> This example requires Firefox 18 or a more recent version. 
>   ...
>
> Example: **Write a string to a file**
>
> These examples require Firefox 19 or a more recent version.

Is that to say FF 18 only supports reading and FF19 supports both reading and writing?

Furthermore, from [Recent changes to OS.File](http://dutherenverseauborddelatable.wordpress.com/2014/04/08/recent-changes-to-os-file/)

> To write a string, you can now pass the string directly to
>   writeAtomic:
>
> `OS.File.writeAtomic(path, "Here is a string", { encoding: "utf-8"})`
>
> Similarly, you can now read strings from read:
>
> `OS.File.read(path, { encoding: "utf-8" } );` // Resolves to a string.
>
> Doing this is at least as fast as calling TextEncoder/TextDecoder
>   yourself (see below).

I have tested above (without `TextEncoder`/`TextDecoder`) on FF30 and it works fine... but which versions is it available on?

Finally, `NetUtil.jsm/FileUtils` will create a file if it does not exist when using `FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream(file)`.

How does file creation work on `OS.File`? Is it automatically created? Does it require a `if(!OS.File.exists(path))` and then how to create one?

The documentation for the recommended method is very limited and examples are hard to come by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that to say FF 18 only supports reading and FF19 supports both reading and writing?

Yes and no. Firefox 18 did support writing to some extend IIRC, but the API changed in 19 so that the example you're referring to does only apply to 19.
Not that it should really concern you... Firefox 18 and 19 are long *end-of-life* and therefore unsupported with known security issues and users should **really upgrade ASAP**.

> I have tested above (without TextEncoder/TextDecoder) on FF30 and it works fine ...but the question is which versions is it available on?

`writeAtomic` with an `encoding` option is available since Firefox 22, while `read` with an `encoding` flag is available since Firefox 30.

> How does file creation work on OS.file? Is it automatically created? Does it require a if(!OS.File.exists(path)) and then how to create one?

`OS.File.writeAtomic` will create the file if it doesn't exist already. Similarly `OS.File.open` in write mode will also create a file, except when you specify `existing: true` in the options.

You cannot read from a file that does not exist. An error will be raised.

```
OS.File.read("/somefile").then(function(data) {
  // do something with the retrieved data;
}, function(ex) {
  if (ex.becauseNoSuchFile) {
    // File does not exist);
  }
  else {
    // Some other error
  }
});
```

Or [`Task.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Task.jsm)-style:

```
try {
  var data = yield OS.File.read("/somefile");
}
catch (ex if ex.becauseNoSuchFile) {
  // File does not exist.
}
catch (ex) {
  // Some other error
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete explanation. Since `writeAtomic` with `encoding` has been available since FF 22 (a safe bet), in case one wants to use `OS.file.jsm`, would it be safer (AFA compatibility) to use `writeAtomic` with `encoding` PLUS older `read` with TextEncoder/TextDecoder OR use for example 'xmlhttprequest' for reading and `writeAtomic`? (file is JSON) In case of XHR, how do we get to profileDir without using `OS.Path.join` or `FileUtils.getFile`? Thank you :)

Comment: I still prefer async XHR for reading of text/JSON files, but that is a personal preference. `OS.File` should be actually better in regards to performance and not blocking the main thread, in particular the newer `encoding`-enabled version. As for your other question: There should be some questions around on SO somewhere, but in short [`ProfD`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Getting_files_in_special_directories) and [`.newFileURI(...).spec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O#nsIFile_and_path_strings)

Comment: I also like XHR. The code for getting a file in `ProfD` without using `FileUtils.jsm` seems rather long!

Comment: `OS.File.exists` returns a promise, not a boolean. So you have to do this: [GitHubGist :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-HowToOSFileExist.js
](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/3bb623b7de6973596bc1)

Comment: I see now...thank you. May I ask ..... how can we get a url from `OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.profileDir, filename)` that could be accessed via XHR? I find XHR much easier to work with.

Comment: Use the regular `ProfD` stuff, or create an `nsIFile` instance using the path and `nsIIOService.newFileURI`.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I have done: `Services.dirsvc.get` & `file.append` & `Services.io.newFileURI` & `spec`. I was wondering if it was possible to get it directly from `OS.Path.join` but `Services.io.newFileURI` on it runs into error: _NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIIOService2.newFileURI]_

Comment: This is how to make it a file uri: [GitHubGist :: yajd / _ff-addon-snippet-FileURIFromOSFileJoin.js](https://gist.github.com/yajd/fc2c2a50966f260dee0c). Although I prefer `OS.File`. I don't know why @nmaier prefers XHR unless you're trying to support old firefox versions. `OS.File` is the future man a lot of work is going into it and its superb work.

Comment: @Noitidart I *personally* prefer XHR still mostly because I'm used to it and it's sometimes easier to use. `OS.File` is nice, but not really mature (as can be seen by the `encoding` part of the question) or very stable yet and has a bunch of inefficiencies with certain use cases. I personally fixed some bugs in `OS.File` in the past. Some of these bugs were quite grave... Not all of the fixes made it into the release version yet (or Nightly even), but that's usually bugs with more advanced uses. The high-level helpers such as `OS.File.writeAtomic` and `OS.File.read` usually work as expected.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. AFA URL, importing FileUtils only for that reason seems excessive as the same can be done without it (with Services.jsm only). IMHO, **The promise of the promise isn't that promising** ;) On a more serious note, the error handling of the promise hasn't been inspiring to me. Error handling of XHR is simple. At the moment I have written a hybrid module using XHR to read and `writeAtomic` to write which would be supported by FF 22+

Comment: Have a look at Task.jsm I already mentioned in my answer. It greatly simplifies promises and also lets you use regular try/catch exception handling instead of that nasty `.then(success, error)` stuff.

Comment: Thank you nmaier. I did indeed study your examples. Personally, I prefer functions that natively return errors such as null, -1 etc. I have never been keen on functions that throw errors/exception and prevent the rest of the code from running and thus the error has be be caught by alternative means and always try to avoid them. The only one that I am forced to use use is  JSON.parse and frankly, I would have preferred a function that returns some value on error instead of using try/catch....but that is my personal view :) PS. I left an note on above Github thread for Noitidart with more info.

Comment: @erosman I just saw your comment on the gist, man github needs to alert people about comments. I replied: https://gist.github.com/yajd/fc2c2a50966f260dee0c#comment-1358379 with `OS.Path.toFileURI` if you just want the file uri string and not the nsIFileURI object.